# Using an if statement to test if JTextField is an integer

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, actionlistener, jtextfield

I want my program to be able to tell if what is inside my two JTextFields is an integer or a String.

**CODE**

```
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(inputH.getText().equals(" Set Height ") || 
                        inputW.getText().equals(" Set Width ")){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
          "Change Height And Width To A Number.",
          "Change Height To A Number",
          JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }                  

                }
            });
```

This if statement tests if what is in the JTextField is `" Set Height "` or `" Set Width "` but i want them to test if what is in them is a number, how would I do that?

i cant figure out the `Integer.ParseInt`. Please help.

Comment: Just use a [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Comment: How should input look to be accepted as integer? Can it be bigger then 2147483647 (max int)? Can it be negative? Can there be spaces, dots or any other characters in text field?

Comment: @Pshemo no, just numbers that are java integers

Comment: So (just to make sure) only numbers in range `[-2147483648; 2147483647]`?

Comment: You should also take a look at [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) and [examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter), which will allow you to ensure that what is entered into the field is always what you are expecting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure exactly where in your code the test is being performed, but you can use this method to determine if a String is an integer:

```
public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
    try { 
        Integer.parseInt(s); 
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
        return false; 
    }
    // if exception isn't thrown, then it is an integer
    return true;
}
```

Less expensive none exception based way, assuming your code does not need to throw an exception:

```
public static boolean isInt(String s){
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            if(!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))){
                 return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Exceptions should not be used for "normal" non-exceptional tests.  It's generally considered poor form, and is very inefficient (generating a stack trace is costly).

Comment: I thought he might want to throw an exception. I added a non exception based way

Answer (score 2):

For restricting a User from entering anything but `digits`, you can set a [**DocumentFilter**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) on the `JTextField`.

Here is a small example :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter.FilterBypass;

public class InputInteger
{
    private JTextField tField;
    private MyDocumentFilter documentFilter;

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Input Integer Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        tField = new JTextField(10);
        ((AbstractDocument)tField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(
                new MyDocumentFilter());        
        contentPane.add(tField); 

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new InputInteger().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}

class MyDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter
{   
    @Override
    public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fp
            , int offset, String string, AttributeSet aset)
                                throws BadLocationException
    {
        int len = string.length();
        boolean isValidInteger = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (!Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i)))
            {
                isValidInteger = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isValidInteger)
            super.insertString(fp, offset, string, aset);
        else
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fp, int offset
                    , int length, String string, AttributeSet aset)
                                        throws BadLocationException
    {
        int len = string.length();
        boolean isValidInteger = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (!Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i)))
            {
                isValidInteger = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isValidInteger)
            super.replace(fp, offset, length, string, aset);
        else
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }
}
```

### Or one can simply use this approach, as given by @Carlos Heuberger

```
@Override
public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int off
                     , String str, AttributeSet attr) 
                               throws BadLocationException 
{
    // remove non-digits
    fb.insertString(off, str.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attr);
} 
@Override
public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int off
      , int len, String str, AttributeSet attr) 
                       throws BadLocationException 
{
    // remove non-digits
    fb.replace(off, len, str.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attr);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can process the key event in the `action` method also. Try this

First make a `JTextField`

```
JTextField j=new JTextField();
```

Then add `KeyListner` to this JTextField as

```
    j.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(arg0.getKeyCode()>57 || arg0.getKeyCode()<48) {
                    //your error message and other handling code here
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(PatentFrame, "Only integer allowed", "Message title",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

48 is ASCII code for 0 and 57 is ASCII code for 9. You can also ignore virtual keys like shift. [See ASCII chart](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: Three things as to why your approach is not good : __1.)__ Even if you press a `non - digit` value, still the `JTextField` will take it, though no doubt it will show you the message. __2.)__ If condition should include __||__ and not __&&__ for it to work, since there is no `KeyCode` value, that is __less than 0 and at the same time greater than 9__. __3.)__ Even if you press `Shift` key or `Escape` still it will show you the same message, which means it's working against the normal functioning as well.

Comment: -1 for suggesting a keyListener for validation (it's incomplete: f.i. misses pasted text)